# Create tables automatically in dockerised Cassandra 4.x

Tags: bash, docker, cassandra

With the below I am able to build and start a Cassandra image with the keyspace and table I need in place ready for my application to work with.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM cassandra:3.11.9

COPY custom-docker-entrypoint.sh /custom-docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/custom-docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["cassandra", "-f"]
```

custom-docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

CQL="
CREATE KEYSPACE testkeyspace WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testkeyspace.video(userid text, videoid text, title TEXT, creationdate TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (userid, videoid));
"

until echo $CQL | cqlsh; do
  echo "cqlsh: Cassandra is unavailable - retry later"
  sleep 2
done &

exec /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

However, when incrementing the Cassandra version to 4.x (4.1.0) in the Dockerfile (`FROM cassandra:4.1.0`), the container exits immediately and the below error is returned.

```
/custom-docker-entrypoint.sh: line 17: /docker-entrypoint.sh: No such file or directory
```

I'm assuming something fundamental has changed with the Cassandra docker image since the 3.x versions, is there a way achieve the same result of creating keyspace/table in the 4.x image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message stated that file `docker-entrypoint.sh` is not more available at `/`. There is no reason why the rest should not be fine. try with

```
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

[source](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/bbe25add57171af90838151e419b7cdafc921e3c/4.1/Dockerfile#L169)